# spending money to dick around

Tags: phrase-usage

Is the phrase "dick around" a bit rude or vulgar? Or is it neutral?

You're not **spending money to dick around** for 12 weeks and put your nose to the desk for the last two …
— Kaylee Kean
I know I don't **have time to dick around** with people who aren't serious.
— Derek Stonebarger

Source:  [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dick%20around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a bit vulgar but not too extreme. You should avoid it in poilte company, formal situations or with people you don't know. In casual conversation, it is generally acceptable and might even stretch to being appropriate in a more casual work conversation if you know the people well enough but use it with a  bit of caution.

Note: This is coming from my experience in Britain. It may be considered more of less vulgar in other parts of the world.

You can see on the definition that you linked that it says: "informal + somewhat vulgar"